# Why does one thread in privatethread() share the same memory address as the global variable in OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

Suppose we have a variable `var=100`. The clause `private(var)` creates **n additional** variables, assigning one to each of the **n** threads:

```
Before parallelism, var's value and address are 100, 0x7ffd683992bc

private parallel region:

var's value and address in thread 3 are 3, 0x7feb115ffde8
var's value and address in thread 0 are 0, 0x7ffd68399258
var's value and address in thread 1 are 1, 0x7feb129ffde8
var's value and address in thread 2 are 2, 0x7feb11fffde8

After private parallelism, var's value and address are 100, 0x7ffd683992bc
```

This works exactly as intended. However, creating a `threadprivate` region, we notice:

```
Before parallelism, var's value and address are 100 and 0x7f685615c7bc

threadprivate parallel region:

var's value and address in thread 0 are 0 and 0x7f685615c7bc
var's value and address in thread 3 are 6 and 0x7f6854c006bc
var's value and address in thread 1 are 2 and 0x7f68560006bc
var's value and address in thread 2 are 4 and 0x7f68556006bc

After first tp parallelism, var's value and address are 0 and 0x7f685615c7bc
```

As you can see, `thread 0`'s copy shares the same address as the original variable and changes here reflect out of the parallel region as well.

All of `private()`, `firstprivate()`, and `lastprivate()` spawn **n additional** variables, while `threadprivate()` spawns only **n-1 more**. What is the reason for this behavior and why is it intended to work this way?

Comment: Cause only n-1 additional vars are needed for n-1 additional threads? Keep in mind that you start with one thread.

Comment: @ikegami which is unlike the other privates right? Why should the global variable be affected?

Comment: "The threadprivate directive specifies that variables are replicated, with each thread having its own copy. " You have demonstrated that this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`threadprivate` is used on static or global variables to give one copy per thread with global extent (so the variable continues to exist for the life of the thread), whereas `{first|last|}private` declare that a variable should be allocated locally in each thread on entry to the parallel region, and then destroyed on exit from the parallel region.

OpenMP specifies that thread zero inside a parallel region is the thread that executed the `parallel` directive ([OpenMP Standard](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.2/openmpse3.html#x16-150001.3:%7E:text=becomes%20the%20primary%20thread%20of%20the%20new%20team) paragraph 9: "When any thread encounters a parallel construct, the thread creates a team of itself and zero or more additional threads and becomes the primary thread of the new team."), therefore it will clearly continue to use the existing, already allocated, `threadprivate` variable for that pre-existing thread.

The behaviour that you are seeing is therefore exactly what you should expect. A `threadprivate` variable exists for the whole of the thread's lifetime, and a new instance will not be created for the, pre-existing, thread zero inside a new parallel region.